# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart

Tags: java, android

I am using Android studio and I am executing multiple insert and create command in an `onCreate` method, while debugging the app, the app throws an exception called

> Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart
>   [int, class java.lang.String]

I have no clue about the exception and it seems to be new. this is my `onCreate` method

DB_Helper.java:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FILTER);
    database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PRODUCT);
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO filters(product_id,Fair_Trade_Sourcing,Fair_Wages,Gender_Equal_Hiring,Gives_Back_To_Charity,Local_Production,Biodegradable_products,Carbon_natrual,Energy_Saving_Practices,Organic_Materials,Recycled_materials,B_Corporation,Fair_Trade_USA,Fairtrade_International,WRAP,GOTS) VALUES('1002','1','1','0','0','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1');");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO filters(product_id,Fair_Trade_Sourcing,Fair_Wages,Gender_Equal_Hiring,Gives_Back_To_Charity,Local_Production,Biodegradable_products,Carbon_natrual,Energy_Saving_Practices,Organic_Materials,Recycled_materials,B_Corporation,Fair_Trade_USA,Fairtrade_International,WRAP,GOTS) VALUES('1003','1','1','0','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1');");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO filters(product_id,Fair_Trade_Sourcing,Fair_Wages,Gender_Equal_Hiring,Gives_Back_To_Charity,Local_Production,Biodegradable_products,Carbon_natrual,Energy_Saving_Practices,Organic_Materials,Recycled_materials,B_Corporation,Fair_Trade_USA,Fairtrade_International,WRAP,GOTS) VALUES('1004','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1');");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO filters(product_id,Fair_Trade_Sourcing,Fair_Wages,Gender_Equal_Hiring,Gives_Back_To_Charity,Local_Production,Biodegradable_products,Carbon_natrual,Energy_Saving_Practices,Organic_Materials,Recycled_materials,B_Corporation,Fair_Trade_USA,Fairtrade_International,WRAP,GOTS) VALUES('1005','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1');");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO product(product_id,productname,description) values('1002','cde','xyz')");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO product(product_id,productname,description) values('1003','Dhirish','xyz')");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO product(product_id,productname,description) values('1004','Kesav','xyz')");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO product(product_id,productname,description) values('1005','Bala','xyz')");
    database.execSQL(sql);
}
```

while debugging I found that the exception is thrown from the line

```
database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PRODUCT);
```

This is the `CREATE_TABLE_PRODUCT` string:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PRODUCT =
            "create table if not exists product (product_id text primary key autoincrement, "+"Productname text not null,"+" Description text);";
```

and finally this is my stacktrace:

```
26888-26888/com.example.kedu.futurewear E/BoostFramework:
BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String] 04-24 00:57:04.209
26888-26888/com.example.kedu.futurewear  E/BoostFramework:
BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String]
```

this is how i call the `onCreate` method:

```
ProductDataSource pds= new ProductDataSource(this);.
pds.open();
```

inside the ProductDataSource class :

```
public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: `onCreate()` is executed when your activity loads and it expects parameter to be a bundle savedInstance. What you can do is you can create another method in `onCreate()` and pass these parameters `SQLiteDatabase database` And the exception is loud and clear method doesn't exists

Comment: yes i am doing this while creating an object for the class lemme edit the code and why does it say method does not exists? i have created one

Comment: @Lokesh i have edited the code

Comment: You can't use `AUTOINCREMENT` with a `TEXT` column. It needs to be `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, though you should just omit `AUTOINCREMENT`, in that case, unless you know you absolutely need it: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html. Those log messages are likely unrelated to your issue.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. it worked